# How to write a Cloud Function to listen and respond events such as when a file is created, changed, or removed?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, etl

In GCP, I am having trouble finding an example on how to listen and respond to Cloud Storage events such as when a file is created, changed, or removed.

I tried looking at the GCP docs on how to do this, but there is nothing there. I am looking for a simple Python example using Cloud Functions to listen and respond to when a file is created, changed, or removed in my GCS Bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger a [Cloud Function V2](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) on a `Cloud Storage` event :

```bash
gcloud functions deploy YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME \
--gen2 \
--trigger-event-filters="type=EVENT_TYPE" \
--trigger-event-filters="bucket=YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET" \
...
```

- `YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME` is the `Cloud Function` name
- `EVENT_TYPE` is the `GCS` file event (Object finalized, Object deleted
  ...). Check the link above on the doc for the different event types
- `YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET` is the `GCS` bucket concerned by the event

For the code of the `Cloud Function`, you check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions#cloudevent-example-python) :

```py
import functions_framework

# Register a CloudEvent function with the Functions Framework
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def my_cloudevent_function(cloud_event):
  # Your code here
  # Access the CloudEvent data payload via cloud_event.data
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. So, is this code written like this or does it need to be within a Python function?

Comment: You're welcome, the code snippet I shared allows to create the trigger based on a GCS file event. Example, when a file is added to the bucket, it will trigger the `Cloud Function` with the name `YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME`. Of course you have to create the `Cloud Function` (with `Python` for example).

Comment: I edited my answer with a link and an example of code snippet for the `Cloud Function`.

Comment: Ah, that makese sense - thank you very much. Also, in the Python function, where do I find the code to write for checking if a file has changed in my GCS Bucket?

Comment: In the gcloud command you have to set the event type that indicates an update in GCS, example `type =OBJECT_METADATA_UPDATE` will trigger your Cloud Function only if the file changed in the bucket